# IOCP GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns with null lpOverlapped

Tags: c#, iocp

I'm trying to write IOCP server with C# using Win32API, imported from `kernel32.dll` and `ws2_32.dll`.

The problem occurs within worker threads. If I make frequent request to the server, it dies within a ten seconds. (break the loop!) Detailed situation is, after `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` function returns `false`, returned integer pointer `lpOverlapped` is `NULL`, and `GetLastWin32Error()` returns code 735, which is `ERROR_ABANDONED_WAIT_0`.

The error is described in msdn as follow:

> If a call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` fails because the completion port handle associated with it is closed while the call is outstanding, the function returns `FALSE`, **lpOverlapped* will be `NULL`, and `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_ABANDONED_WAIT_0`.

But when I debugged the program, `completionPort` variable was valid and it doesn't seems like completion port has been closed. please take a look at the code.

```
public int WorkerThread()
{       
    ...
    while (true) {
        // Wait until all socket I/O completes.
        bool ret = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
            completionPort: completionPort,
            lpNumberOfBytesTransferred: out bytesTransferred,
            lpCompletionKey: out intPtrPerHandleData,
            lpOverlapped: out intPtrOverlapped,
            dwMilliseconds: uint.MaxValue);

        // WHAT IS WRONG!?!??!
        if (intPtrOverlapped == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Logger.ErrorLog();
            break;
        }

        // Recover PerIoData and PerHandleData from IntPtr
        ...

        // Disconnected from client.
        if (ret == false && bytesTransferred == 0) {
            socketRefCount[perHandleData.Socket]--;
            if (socketRefCount[perHandleData.Socket] == 0)
            {
                socketRefCount.Remove(perHandleData.Socket);
                perHandleData.Socket.Close();
            }
            gchPerHandleData.Free();
            gchPerIoData.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

I thought completion port was O.K., so I first changed the `break` clause to `continue`. Then it makes 735 error (`ERROR_ABANDONED_WAIT_0`) first, and then infinitely makes error code 6 (`WSA_INVALID_HANDLE`). Following is simplified log.

```
Thread[4] : Error[735]
Thread[5] : Error[735]
Thread[7] : Error[735]
Thread[6] : Error[735]
Thread[4] : Error[6]
Thread[5] : Error[6]
Thread[7] : Error[6]
Thread[6] : Error[6]
Thread[4] : Error[6]
Thread[5] : Error[6]
...
```

So there IS a problem with completion port, right? Can you explain what is the problem I've encountered with and possible cause to this problem? (I just made about ten to twenty of 50 bytes messages per second. I think it is very few, but server fails to afford it even for a minute!) Do I have to reconstruct I/O completion port and worker threads every time this error occurs? (i.e. reset the server?)

--- Update!
Added full version of worker thread code: http://ideone.com/J0flmC

Comment: You *must* test the "ret" variable first.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, but it seems testing `ret` first will not change the result if completion port itself has a problem...

Comment: Your code is broken.  Fix your code, then update your question.

Comment: @HansPassant I added link to a code! Is this enough for recognizing problem?

Comment: I didn't even bother to look at the question, because you're doing the whole thing wrong. If you want to use IOCP with a network socket, use an asynchronous API of the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class. It uses IOCP underneath.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am doing kind of a school project that implements IOCP server without using .Net Soket library (using native Win32 api)..